# <button> and <a> seem have different line-heights, how to go around it?

Tags: html, css

The button is 2px bigger then the a tag with same styles. Any ideas why is it doing it and how to fix it?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duSQD/4/)

```
<a href="">Some Text</a>
<button> Some Text</button>

a, button {
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  display: inline-block;
  color:black;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: you could probably use min-height

Comment: The button is 2px bigger because you're not taking into account the border for the button.

Comment: I used border:none in css, its not helping

Comment: I tend to set both `line-height` and `height` to the same value, as the text within buttons rarely wraps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button has padding. 
Set `padding : 0;` on the button and they will look the same

Firefox has its own thing...
Try adding the following:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: you have padding in your css style here, but not on JSFiddle

Comment: Sorry, I added padding:0 to fiddle, but forgot to update to new version before posting here. As you can see, setting padding to 0 does not help